# align by any character in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How would one align the RHS by the "8"s in the following? I tried adding another column, and then left aligning the "999998" right, and the "00001" left, but there was a giant gap...

```
Table~\ref{tab:myNines} comes from the algebraic identitiy, 
$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, taking $a=10^n$ and $b=1$.

    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c l}
    $9^2$ &$=$ &$81$\\
    $99^2$ &$=$ &$9801$\\
    $999^2$ &$=$ &$998001$\\
    $9999^2$ &$=$ &$99980001$\\
    $99999^2$ &$=$ &$9999800001$\\
    $999999^2$ &$=$ &$999998000001$\\
    $9999999^2$ &$=$ &$99999980000001$\\
    $99999999^2$ &$=$ &$9999999800000001$\\
    $999999999^2$ &$=$ &$999999998000000001$\\
    $9999999999^2$ &$=$ &$99999999980000000001$
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Note the Nines}
    \label{tab:myNines}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Piece of cake with the [dcolumn](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package and its `D` column type.

I'm pretty sure that the `D` column type is used much more frequently with `.` or `,` as the decimal marker. However, there's no reason for not using some other symbol -- say, the numeral `8` -- as the input and output "decimal marker".

Aside: By using an `array` enviroment instead of a `tabular` environment, one doesn't have to provide all those `$` inline-math delimiters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type
\begin{document}

Table~\ref{tab:myEights} comes from the algebraic identity $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, putting $a=10^n$ and $b=1$.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} D{8}{8}{9.10}} % '9.10': 9 digits before '8', 10 digits after '8'
9^2 & 81\\
99^2 & 9801\\
999^2 & 998001\\
9999^2 & 99980001\\
99999^2 & 9999800001\\
999999^2 & 999998000001\\
9999999^2 & 99999980000001\\
99999999^2 & 9999999800000001\\
999999999^2 & 999999998000000001\\
9999999999^2 & 99999999980000000001
\end{array}$
\caption{Note the Eights} \label{tab:myEights}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- some additional considerations, in no particular order>

- If you wanted to highlight the `8` numerals by, say, rendering them in blue, all you'd have to change is (a) load the `xcolor` package and (b) replace `D{8}{8}` with `D{8}{\color{blue}8}`.
- If you want to increase the line spacing in the `array` by, say, 30%, just issue the instruction `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}` immediately before `\begin{array}`.
- If you're free to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, you could generate the contents of the `array` environment programmatically via a Lua `for` loop. E.g., to generate a nine-row `array`, you could run

  ```
   $\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} D{8}{8}{8.9}} 
   \directlua{
  ```

```lua
    for i=1,9 do
      j = math.floor(10^i-1) % convert to 'integer' data type
      tex.sprint ( j .. "^2 & " .. j*j .. "\\\\")
    end
```

```tex
   }
   \end{array}$
```

---

*Second addendum*: In the preceding code, values of `n` greater than about 10 can lead to overflows in the calculations that generate `n^2`. (Lua can do integer arithmetic; however, overflows can still occur.) If you plan on showing arrays with more than 10 rows, you could switch to performing *string operations* to generate `n^2`. (Observe that for an integer `n` greater than 1, `n^2` may be written as the concatenation of n-1 copies of `9`, 1 copy of `8`, n-1 copies of `0`, and 1 copy of `1`.)

The following code produces two such arrays -- the first for `n=1`, and the second for `n=20`. Observe that the code for the second argument of the `D` column type is set to `\color{blue}8` and that the third argument of the `D` column type is evaluated "on the fly" -- `n-1` digits before the `8` marker and `n` digits after the `8` marker -- in order to guaranteed a compact appearance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\color' command
\usepackage{dcolumn} % for 'D' column type

% The Lua function 'myarray' does almost all of the work
\directlua{%
```

```lua
  function myarray ( n ) % "n" should be an integer
    tex.sprint ( "\\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} D{8}{\\color{blue}8}{"
                 .. n-1 .. "." .. n .."}}" )
    for i=1,n do
        tex.sprint ( string.rep ("9",i  ) .. "^2 & " ..
                     string.rep ("9",i-1) .. "8"     .. 
                     string.rep ("0",i-1) .. "1\\\\" )
    end
    tex.sprint ( "\\end{array}" )
  end
```

```tex
}
% LaTeX utility macro to access the Lua function
\newcommand\myarray[1]{$\directlua{myarray(#1)}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\myarray{1}

\medskip
\myarray{20}

\caption{Note the nines and zeroes} 
\label{tab:myNines}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use an additional alignment point before the digits 8. Using `@{}` removes the intercolumn space. To ease input, I inserted `{}={}` between the first and second column automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Table~\ref{tab:myNines} comes from the algebraic identitiy,
$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, taking $a=10^n$ and $b=1$.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
$\begin{array}{ l @{{}={}} r@{}l }
9^2           &          &81\\
99^2          &         9&801\\
999^2         &        99&8001\\
9999^2        &       999&80001\\
99999^2       &      9999&800001\\
999999^2      &     99999&8000001\\
9999999^2     &    999999&80000001\\
99999999^2    &   9999999&800000001\\
999999999^2   &  99999999&8000000001\\
9999999999^2  & 999999999&80000000001\\
\end{array}$

\caption{Note the Nines}
\label{tab:myNines}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even let TeX do the computations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_squarenines:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { 9 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \bigintcalcSqr { \l_tmpa_tl } }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { 8 } { &8 }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpc_tl { \l_tmpa_tl^2 & \l_tmpb_tl \exp_not:N \\ }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makenines}{m}
 {% #1 = number of rows
  $\begin{array}{ l @{{}={}} r @{} l }
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpc_tl
  \int_step_function:nN { #1 } \__egreg_squarenines:n
  \l_tmpc_tl
  \end{array}$
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Table~\ref{tab:myNines} comes from the algebraic identitiy, 
$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, taking $a=10^n$ and $b=1$.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\makenines{10}

\caption{Note the Nines}
\label{tab:myNines}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\makenines{15}

\caption{Note the Nines}
\label{tab:myNines-big}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use TeX primitive `\halign` directly:

```
\halign{$#$\hfil${}={}$&\hfil#&#\hfil \cr
9^2           &          &81          \cr
99^2          &         9&801         \cr
999^2         &        99&8001        \cr
9999^2        &       999&80001       \cr
99999^2       &      9999&800001      \cr
999999^2      &     99999&8000001     \cr
9999999^2     &    999999&80000001    \cr
99999999^2    &   9999999&800000001   \cr
999999999^2   &  99999999&8000000001  \cr
9999999999^2  & 999999999&80000000001 \cr
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `alignat` from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) in two different ways, depending on the alignment of the first "column":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Table~\ref{tab:myNines} comes from the algebraic identitiy, $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, taking $a = 10^n$ and $b = 1$.
\begin{table}
  \begin{alignat*}{3}
    & 9^2          & {}={} &&          &81          \\
    & 99^2         & {}={} &&         9&801         \\
    & 999^2        & {}={} &&        99&8001        \\
    & 9999^2       & {}={} &&       999&80001       \\
    & 99999^2      & {}={} &&      9999&800001      \\
    & 999999^2     & {}={} &&     99999&8000001     \\
    & 9999999^2    & {}={} &&    999999&80000001    \\
    & 99999999^2   & {}={} &&   9999999&800000001   \\
    & 999999999^2  & {}={} &&  99999999&8000000001  \\
    & 9999999999^2 & {}={} && 999999999&80000000001
  \end{alignat*}

  \begin{alignat*}{2}
             9^2 & ={} &          &81          \\
            99^2 & ={} &         9&801         \\
           999^2 & ={} &        99&8001        \\
          9999^2 & ={} &       999&80001       \\
         99999^2 & ={} &      9999&800001      \\
        999999^2 & ={} &     99999&8000001     \\
       9999999^2 & ={} &    999999&80000001    \\
      99999999^2 & ={} &   9999999&800000001   \\
     999999999^2 & ={} &  99999999&8000000001  \\
    9999999999^2 & ={} & 999999999&80000000001
  \end{alignat*}
  
  \caption{Note the Nines}
  \label{tab:myNines}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```